# How to successfully change `FakeRequest` to `RequestBuilder`

Tags: scala, playframework

As the Play 2.4 migration guide specifies:

`FakeRequest has been replaced by RequestBuilder.`

I have a question how to change or migrate `play.api.test.FakeRequest` to `Http.RequestBuilder` when I have something like:

```
val result = controller.update.apply {
            FakeRequest()
              .withLoggedIn(config)(loggedInUser)
}
```

So how to use `withLoggedIn` in `RequestBuilder`. I don't see anything similar.

Comment: Play documentation says "FakeRequest has been replaced by RequestBuilder"  for Java API, but it still exists in Scala API so you can use it.

Comment: Well of course , but I have a task to remove it.

Comment: There is nothing similar in RequestBuilder. You have to implement something that will fake loggedInUser, like adding username and session to the .session